# Redirect Apache Don't Work

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm trying to redirect this:
http://www.cartolaleague.com.br/acessoBanco -> http://www.cartolaleague.com.br/acessoBanco/

But it does not work, someone could help me?
If I access to the bar at the end it works without no bar

```
#
# -- ConfiguraÃ§Ãµes do site: cartolaleague.com.br

#
# -- Proibo o acesso atravÃ©s do ip. http://178.32.54.133/
<VirtualHost 178.32.54.133:80>
    ServerName 178.32.54.133
    <Directory />
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>

#
# -- Configuro o site.
<VirtualHost 178.32.54.133:80>
    ServerName www.cartolaleague.com.br
    ServerAdmin contato@cartolaleague.com.br
    Alias /acessoBanco /var/www/phpmyadmin
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cartolaleague/htdocs/
    <Directory /var/www/cartolaleague>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerSignature Off
    CustomLog "/Dados/Restrito/Logs/Apache/Cartola League/Acesso/acessoCartolaLeague.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/Dados/Restrito/Logs/Apache/Cartola League/Erro/erroCartolaLeague.log"
</VirtualHost>

#
# -- Configuro o site para www.
<VirtualHost 178.32.54.133:80>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    ServerName cartolaleague.com.br
    ServerAdmin contato@cartolaleague.com.br
    RedirectMatch /^acessoBanco /var/www/phpmyadmin/
    Redirect Permanent / http://www.cartolaleague.com.br/
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>

#
# -- Tratando os erros.
ErrorDocument 301 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume301.html
ErrorDocument 400 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume404.html
ErrorDocument 405 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume405.html
ErrorDocument 406 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume406.html
ErrorDocument 407 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume407.html
ErrorDocument 408 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume408.html
ErrorDocument 409 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume409.html
ErrorDocument 500 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume500.html
ErrorDocument 502 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /tapumes/tapumeHTTP/tapume504.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `301 Redirect` instead of `Permanent` and list the old location first then new location after:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.cartolaleague.com.br http://www.cartolaleague.com
```